# unable to run test containers in dev environment

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, testcontainers

I am using test containers to test my spring boot kafka avro implementation.

Below is the code I have used for test container

```
          properties = {
"spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT",

                "spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
                "spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer"
            })
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    @Import(KafkaProducer.class)
    class SpringBootKafkaAvroConsumerApplicationTests {
    
        @Autowired MockMvc mockMvc;
        @Autowired PersonRepository personRepository;
        @Autowired KafkaProducer kafkaProducer;
    
        private static final Network KAFKA_NETWORK = Network.newNetwork();
        private static final String CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_VERSION = "7.4.1";
        private static final DockerImageName KAFKA_IMAGE =
                DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka").withTag(CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_VERSION);
        private static final KafkaContainer KAFKA =
                new KafkaContainer(KAFKA_IMAGE)
                        .withNetwork(KAFKA_NETWORK)
                        .withKraft()
                        .withEnv("KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR", "1")
                        .withEnv("KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR", "1");
    
        private static final SchemaRegistryContainer SCHEMA_REGISTRY =
                new SchemaRegistryContainer(CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_VERSION)
                        .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2));
    
        static {
            KAFKA.start();
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY.withKafka(KAFKA).start();
            // Should be set after container is started
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY.withEnv("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS", SCHEMA_REGISTRY.getSchemaUrl());
        }
    
        @DynamicPropertySource
        static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
            // Connect our Spring application to our Testcontainers Kafka instance
            registry.add("spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers", KAFKA::getBootstrapServers);
            registry.add("spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers", KAFKA::getBootstrapServers);
            registry.add(
                    "spring.kafka.producer.properties.schema.registry.url",
                    SCHEMA_REGISTRY::getSchemaUrl);
            registry.add("spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url", SCHEMA_REGISTRY::getSchemaUrl);
        }
    
        private static class SchemaRegistryContainer extends GenericContainer<SchemaRegistryContainer> {
            public static final String SCHEMA_REGISTRY_IMAGE = "confluentinc/cp-schema-registry";
            public static final int SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT = 8081;
    
            public SchemaRegistryContainer() {
                this(CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_VERSION);
            }
    
            public SchemaRegistryContainer(String version) {
                super(DockerImageName.parse(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_IMAGE).withTag(CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_VERSION));
    
                waitingFor(Wait.forHttp("/subjects").forStatusCode(200));
                withExposedPorts(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT);
            }
    
            public SchemaRegistryContainer withKafka(KafkaContainer kafka) {
                return withKafka(kafka.getNetwork(), kafka.getNetworkAliases().get(0) + ":9092");
            }
    
            public SchemaRegistryContainer withKafka(Network network, String bootstrapServers) {
                withNetwork(network);
                withEnv("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME", "schema-registry");
                withEnv(
                        "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS",
                        "PLAINTEXT://" + bootstrapServers);
                return self();
            }
    
            public String getSchemaUrl() {
                return String.format("http://%s:%d", getHost(), getMappedPort(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT));
            }
        }
    
        @Test
        void contextLoads() throws Exception {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setAge(33);
            person.setName("junit");
            this.kafkaProducer.sendMessage(person);
            await().atMost(10, SECONDS)
                    .untilAsserted(() -> assertThat(personRepository.count()).isEqualTo(1));
        }
    }
```

The setup works fine in my local but when I run the build in git hub actions, the build fails

> java.lang.ExceptionInInializerError at
> NativeConstructorAcessorImple.java: -2 Caused by:
> org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException at
> TestContainer.java:56   caused by
> com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException at
> DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:247

The line number points to

```
private static final KafkaContainer KAFKA =
            new KafkaContainer(KAFKA_IMAGE)
                    .withNetwork(KAFKA_NETWORK)
                    .withKraft() //56th line of the error message
                    .withEnv("KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR", "1")
                    .withEnv("KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR", "1");
```

Can someone tell me What is the root cause for this error.

Comment: You don't need a container. https://selectfrom.dev/testing-schema-registry-with-spring-boot-and-spring-kafka-using-mockschemaregistryclient-8374bfe5bc6f

Comment: @OneCricketeer I saw your link and it is pointing to localhost, will it work if I deploy to cloud .My Implementation also works in local host . When I deploy to dev environment it is failing

Comment: That post is using embedded Kafka and a mock server. Both are running on some local test machine yes. I'm just pointing out that containers aren't necessary, you only need Java to mock the interaction with the registry